# How to vertically center a Bootstrap carousel-caption?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel and I am trying to create a caption for the carousel that is always vertically centered and positioned slightly to the left. I have the css for the horizontal positioning.. but when I try to position vertically, the caption doesn't stay put. How can i keep the .carousel-caption always centered vertically and slightly to the left?

HTML:

```
    <!-- start JumboCarousel -->
    <div id="jumboCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden-xs">
            <li data-target="#jumboCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#jumboCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#jumboCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#jumboCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol><!-- end carousel-indicators -->

        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active" id="slide1">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/1920x720&text=Slide+1" alt="Slide 1"></a>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Check Out this Moose</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This text is super engaging and makes you want to click the button.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Learn More</a>
                </div><!-- end carousel-caption -->
            </div><!-- end slide1 -->
            <div class="item" id="slide2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x720&text=Slide+2" alt="Slide 2">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>#Slide Title</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This text is super engaging and makes you want to click the button.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Learn More</a>
                </div><!-- end carousel-caption -->
            </div><!-- end slide2 -->
            <div class="item" id="slide3">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x720&text=Slide+3" alt="Slide 3">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>#Slide Title</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This text is super engaging and makes you want to click the button.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Learn More</a>
                </div><!-- end carousel-caption -->
            </div><!-- end slide3 -->
            <div class="item" id="slide4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x720&text=Slide+4" alt="Slide 4">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>#Slide Title</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This text is super engaging and makes you want to click the button.</p>
                    <button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Learn More</button>
                </div><!-- end carousel-caption -->
            </div><!-- end slide4 -->
        </div><!-- end carousel-inner -->

    </div><!-- end jumboCarousel -->
```

CSS:

```
#jumboCarousel {
    margin-top: 70px;
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 100%;
}
#jumboCarousel img {
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 100%;
}
#jumboCarousel > .carousel-indicators > li {
    border-radius: 0px;
    min-width: 25px;
    background-color: #9d9d9d;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: 10px;;
    margin-left: 10px;;
}
#jumboCarousel > .carousel-indicators > .active {
    background-color: orange;
}
#jumboCarousel .carousel-caption {
    color: black;
    right: 58%;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 500px;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
}
```

anything I do to give the caption a vertical alignment has ended up with the caption getting pushed out of the top of the carousel as the screen-size decreases.. Thanks for the help.

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/aWK6oVRWVo

Comment: like this? http://www.bootply.com/3w0EGqpPYh

Comment: exactly what i needed!! thank you so much, I would have never figured that out.

Comment: Ok, I'll create an answer and explain it a bit

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use the `translateY` function of the CSS property `transform` to vertically align elements. [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) is quite decent, including IE9.
Therefore just add the following to your `.carousel-caption` CSS.

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Now you need to get rid of the extra `bottom` space, added by the default bootstrap CSS. Add the following as well to your `.carousel-caption` CSS.

```
bottom: initial;
```

And last but not least give the parent element, in this case `.item`, the following CSS to prevent blurry elements when it's placed on half a pixel.

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

[**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/uouNl1xyMr)