# Bootstrap carousel: text on image does not center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am experience carousell related problems with my pictures...
For some reason in the 2 later carousel pictures the text is not centeres as it should be (look at my attached image and check out how the text looks on top of the excavator image contra how it looks in the image taken inside a museum). Can someone take a look at my code below?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <!--<h2>Ajoneuvo</h2> -->
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div id="myCarousel123">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">

      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/nordkalk.jpg" alt="Nordkalk" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 id="karuselli">Nordkalk</h3>
          <p id ="karuselli">Nordkalk <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Hammerglass, lisätietoa klikkaamalla</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/nimeton.png" alt="Matias" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 id="karuselli">Matias Mäkikoskela</h3>
          <p id="karuselli">Hammerglass pelasti Matiaksen!</p>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<h2>Kiinteistö</h2> -->
  <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div id="myCarousel123">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">

      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/riihimaki_edit.png" alt="Metsästyslasi" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 id="karuselli" style="text-align:center;"><center>Metsästysmuseo</center></h3>
          <p id="karuselli">Hammerglass vitriinit metsästysmuseossa!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/nimeton-3.png" alt="Vaaksy" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Wääksyn kartano</h3>
          <p>Wääksyn kartano; maneesin ikkunasuojaus</p>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!--<h2>Sää- ja melusuojat</h2> -->

  <div id="myCarousel3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div id="myCarousel123">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">

      <li data-target="#myCarousel3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/nimeton3.png" alt="Tampere" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 id="karuselli">Myllypuronkatu</h3>
          <p id="karuselli">Ce-hyväksytty melusuoja Tampereella!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/nimeton.jpg" alt="Kotka" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Koskenkylä</h3>
          <p>Elinkaarimelusuojausta Ahvenkosken sillalla!</p>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel3" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel3" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>`<?php 
/**
*Template Name:Frontpage 
* 
*@package Wordpress
*@subpackage hammmerglass
*@since hammerglass 0.1 alpha
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <!--<h2>Ajoneuvo</h2> -->
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div id="myCarousel123">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">

      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/nordkalk.jpg" alt="Nordkalk" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 id="karuselli">Nordkalk</h3>
          <p id ="karuselli">Nordkalk <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Hammerglass, lisätietoa klikkaamalla</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/nimeton.png" alt="Matias" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 id="karuselli">Matias Mäkikoskela</h3>
          <p id="karuselli">Hammerglass pelasti Matiaksen!</p>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<h2>Kiinteistö</h2> -->
  <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div id="myCarousel123">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">

      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/riihimaki_edit.png" alt="Metsästyslasi" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 id="karuselli" style="text-align:center;"><center>Metsästysmuseo</center></h3>
          <p id="karuselli">Hammerglass vitriinit metsästysmuseossa!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/nimeton-3.png" alt="Vaaksy" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Wääksyn kartano</h3>
          <p>Wääksyn kartano; maneesin ikkunasuojaus</p>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!--<h2>Sää- ja melusuojat</h2> -->

  <div id="myCarousel3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div id="myCarousel123">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">

      <li data-target="#myCarousel3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/nimeton3.png" alt="Tampere" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 id="karuselli">Myllypuronkatu</h3>
          <p id="karuselli">Ce-hyväksytty melusuoja Tampereella!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/nimeton.jpg" alt="Kotka" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Koskenkylä</h3>
          <p>Elinkaarimelusuojausta Ahvenkosken sillalla!</p>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel3" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel3" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>

This is the code for my css on the frontpage
```

Below you can see the separate css code for the carousel image content:

```
    body { margin-top: 50px; }
#myCarousel {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 562px;
    height:370px;
}
#myCarousel2 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: center;
    width: 562px;
    height: 370px;
}
#myCarousel3 {
    display: block;
    float: center;
    width: 562px;
    height: 370px;
}
#footer {
    background-color: rgb(58,58,58);
    align: bottom;
}

p#footer {
    color:white;
}
p#karuselli {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: white;
} 
h3#karuselli {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
}
h3#museo {
    font-size: 54px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
p#museo {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Is there a reason behind the text in carousel 2 and 3 not being centered? Am I missing a "dominating element" that should be changed?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a Bootstrap carousel-caption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279865/how-to-vertically-center-a-bootstrap-carousel-caption)

Comment: your template look weird to me, it seems you have TWO templates in one (I see 2 get_header() and get_footer()).