# Bootstrap 4 carousel - d-md-flex align-items-md-center brakes col widths

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Can't figure out why slide two is causing such a massive change/shift when viewing on desktop. It appears to be the result of adding a d-md-flex align-items-md-center to the enclosing div. Is there something I am overlooking or an alternate method I should be using?

```
 <div class="container-md py-5">
  <div class="testimonial-circle rounded-circle bg-white px-n2 px-sm-0 mx-n2 mx-sm-0 d-md-flex align-items-md-center">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 offset-md-1 mt-5 text-center">
        <h2 class="font-weight-bold">People LOVE<br />the&nbsp;This Product<sup>&reg;</sup>&nbsp;</h2>
        <p class="d-none d-md-block"><a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Read Reviews</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-10 col-md-5 offset-1">
        <!-- start carousel -->
        <div id="testimonialSlider" class="carousel slide mt-2" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="5"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner pt-2 d-block">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed bibendum fringilla eros, sed accumsan odio semper sit amet. Ut viverra ex velit velit sit.</p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <p class="mb-0">This brakes the layout Why?</p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed bibendum fringilla eros, sed accumsan odio semper sit amet. Ut viverra ex.</p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed bibendum fringilla eros, sed accumsan odio semper sit amet.</p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed bibendum fringilla eros,</p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="d-md-none text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/oral-health/products/dental-water-flosser/WF-11W010-1/">Read Reviews</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<div class="container-md py-5">
    <div class="row align-items-center" style="border: 1px solid blue;">

        <div class="testimonial-circle rounded-circle bg-white d-flex justify-content-start">

            <div class=" text-center" style="width: 25rem; border: 1px solid red;">
                <h2 class="font-weight-bold">People LOVE<br />the&nbsp;This Product<sup>&reg;</sup>&nbsp;</h2>
                <p class="d-none d-md-block"><a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Read Reviews</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class=" " style="flex: 1; border: 1px solid green;">
                <!-- start carousel -->
                <div id="testimonialSlider" class="carousel slide mt-2" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner pt-2 ">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <blockquote class="blockquote">
                                <p class="mb-0">This brakes the layout Why?</p>
                                <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <blockquote class="blockquote">
                                <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed bibendum fringilla eros, sed accumsan odio semper sit amet. Ut viverra ex velit velit sit.</p>
                                <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <blockquote class="blockquote">
                                <p class="mb-0">This brakes the layout Why?</p>
                                <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <p class="d-md-none text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/oral-health/products/dental-water-flosser/WF-11W010-1/">Read Reviews</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation**

- I changed of position of row tag, testimonial-circle must be inside
  the row.
- It was not well resolved from the flex inside the carousel. Pe: the tag on the left
  must have a size and the tag on the right should take advantage of
  all the available space. With a fixed size, the left tag will not be
  modified.

**The main problem is that the flex modified it depending on the size of what it had to incorporate.**

*note: I leave the borders so you can see how the behavior is.*

[run code](https://www.codeply.com/p/zAUDX6yPfl)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks that did it. Funny how flexbox can still be mysterious. The explanation was very helpful for future projects.

Answer (score 1):

The width of your row is changing based on the content because you have your row inside your `testimonial-circle` division. The row needs to be a child of the container. You can add your customer styles to the container if you need customization.

The other problem you’ll have is, because your carousel is all text, the heights will vary. Easiest way to prevent the text boxes from jumping is to normalize all of the slide heights using jQuery.

**Update:** To center the blockquote vertically in the carousel-item, you can use transform per this answer [How to vertically center a Bootstrap carousel-caption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279865/how-to-vertically-center-a-bootstrap-carousel-caption).

```js
function normalizeSlideHeights() {
    $('.carousel').each(function() {
        var items = $('.carousel-item', this);
        // reset the height
        items.css('height', 'auto');
        // set the height
        var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null,
            items.map(function() {
                return $(this).outerHeight()
            }).get());
        items.css('height', maxHeight + 'px');
    })
}

$(window).on(
    'load resize orientationchange',
    normalizeSlideHeights
);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .carousel-indicators {
        bottom: -9px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .carousel-indicators li {
        background-color: #C7C7C7;
    }

    .carousel-item {
        padding: 4px 0;
    }
    .carousel-item.active {
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    .blockquote {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        position: relative;
    }
</style>

<div class="container-md py-5">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 offset-md-1 text-center">
            <h2 class="font-weight-bold mb-4">People LOVE<br />the&nbsp;This Product<sup>&reg;</sup></h2>
            <p class="d-none mb-0 d-md-block"><a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Read Reviews</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-10 col-md-5 offset-1">
            <!-- start carousel -->
            <div id="testimonialSlider" class="carousel slide mt-2" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                    <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner pt-2 d-block">
                    <div class="carousel-item active border" style="height: 150px;">
                        <blockquote class="blockquote">
                            <p class="mb-0 text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed bibendum fringilla eros, sed accumsan odio semper sit amet. Ut viverra ex velit velit sit.</p>
                            <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item border" style="height: 170px;">
                        <blockquote class="blockquote">
                            <p class="mb-0 text-justify">This breakes the layout Why?</p>
                            <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item border" style="height: 150px;">
                        <blockquote class="blockquote">
                            <p class="mb-0 text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item border" style="height: 150px;">
                        <blockquote class="blockquote">
                            <p class="mb-0 text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed bibendum fringilla eros, sed accumsan odio semper sit amet. Ut viverra ex.</p>
                            <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item border" style="height: 150px;">
                        <blockquote class="blockquote">
                            <p class="mb-0 text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed bibendum fringilla eros, sed accumsan odio semper sit amet.</p>
                            <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item border" style="height: 150px;">
                        <blockquote class="blockquote">
                            <p class="mb-0 text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed bibendum fringilla eros,</p>
                            <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite title="Source Title">Verified User</cite></footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <p class="d-md-none w-100 mt-4 text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/oral-health/products/dental-water-flosser/WF-11W010-1/">Read Reviews</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the carousel item height normalization script. This will be helpful. Any thoughts on why h-100 class does not work to make each carousel-item the same height in the row? I wish there was a CSS workaround for this.

Comment: is there a way to center the contents vertically in the normalized carousel-item div?

Comment: The h-100 class doesn’t help in this case as the row (the source for the 100%)  gets its height from the slides and the row’s height keeps changing as the unseen slides are set to `display: none` (no height) – the row has the height of just the current and transitioning slides, which are set to `display: block`. I’ve updated my answer to vertically center your blockquote content.